# Dynamically updating a specific view in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently working on android using `RecyclerView`, let's say I have 2 `TextView` in my custom row, I wanted to dynamically change the text of one in the `TextView`, how can I do that?

I do have the following code in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdaptersOnline adaptersOnline;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<ModelClientInformation> modelOnlineLists = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adaptersOnline = new AdaptersOnline(this, modelOnlineLists);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptersOnline);
    }

    //call this to new row
    public void initializeClient(String id, String data1, String data2){
        this.modelOnlineLists.add(new ModelClientInformation(id, data1, data2));
        adaptersOnline.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Call this method to update textview
    public void updateSpecificViewItem(String theID){
         //get position base on the ID           
         adaptersOnline.updateTextView(
         adaptersOnline.getPositionBaseOnItemID(theID));
    }

}
```

in my Adapter Class

```
public class AdaptersOnline extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptersOnline.TheViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    public List<ModelClientInformation> onlineList;

    public AdaptersOnline(Context mContext, List<ModelClientInformation> modelOnlineList){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.onlineList = modelOnlineList;
    }

    public class TheViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView text1, text2;

        public TheViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TheViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new TheViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TheViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ModelClientInformation info = onlineList.get(position);

        holder.text1.setText(holder.getText1());
        holder.text1.setText(holder.getText2());
    }


    /**Function to Return the size of List**/
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return onlineList.size();
    }

    /**Function to Clear the List**/
    public void clear(){
        onlineList.clear();
    }


    /**Possibly way to update one of the TextView here**/
    public void updateTextView(int position){
        //what should I do to update the TextView
    }

    /*Get the position of item inside data list base on the given ID*/
    public int getPositionBaseOnItemID(String theID) {

    int length = onlineList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        if(onlineList.get(i).getItemID().equals(theID)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; //Item not found
}
}
```

and the Pojo

```
public ModelClientInformation class{

    private String theID, text1, text2;

    public ModelClientInformation(String theID, String text1, String text2){
        this.theID = theID;
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public String getItemID(){
        return theID;
    }

    public String getText1(){
        return text1;
    }

    public String getText2(){
        return text2;
    }

}
```

I'm don't have any idea to do it. . .
Anyone can help me?

**UPDATE:**

Please look at my changes,

1: I want to update one of the `TextView` inside `MainActivity` class by calling `updateSpecificViewItem("theID")`.

2: Get the position of the item base on the given `id` by calling `getPositionBaseOnItemID("theID")`.

3: To finally update the specific item, I want to call `updateTextView(int position)` method.

the only problem I'm facing right now is the `number 3`, how can I update only the `text2` and not the entire item?

Comment: can you explain more..?

Comment: where are you calling the updateTextView method ? on which action do you need to call the method to change the text ?

Comment: sorry for tha late response, I wanted to call the method updateTextView from mainActivity class.

Comment: If you are changing the text on a button click then update your pojo class with updated text and notify the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving my problem

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdaptersOnline adaptersOnline;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<ModelClientInformation> modelOnlineLists = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adaptersOnline = new AdaptersOnline(this, modelOnlineLists);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptersOnline);
    }

    //call this to new row
    public void initializeClient(String id, String data1, String data2){
        this.modelOnlineLists.add(new ModelClientInformation(id, data1, data2));
        adaptersOnline.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Call this method to update specific Item
    public void updateSpecificViewItem(String theID, String newText){      

         int position = adaptersOnline.getPositionBaseOnItemID(theID); // get position base on the ID
         ModelClientInformation oldItem = adaptersOnline.getOnlineList().get(position); // From my Adapter I created a new method `getOnlineList()` that returns the list item of specific position.

         ModelClientInformation newItem = new ModelClientInformation(
                    oldItem.ItemID(), // get and add the old Item ID
                    oldItem.getText1(), // Get and add the old Text1
                    newText // add the new text for text2
            );

        adaptersOnline.updateTextView(position, newItem); // call updateTextView() from the adapter and pass the position and the newItem.
    }

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class AdaptersOnline extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptersOnline.TheViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    public List<ModelClientInformation> onlineList;

    public AdaptersOnline(Context mContext, List<ModelClientInformation> modelOnlineList){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.onlineList = modelOnlineList;
    }

    public class TheViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView text1, text2;

        public TheViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TheViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new TheViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TheViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ModelClientInformation info = onlineList.get(position);

        holder.text1.setText(holder.getText1());
        holder.text1.setText(holder.getText2());
    }


    /**Function to Return the size of List**/
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return onlineList.size();
    }

    /**Function to Clear the List**/
    public void clear(){
        onlineList.clear();
    }

    /**Function to return the Data List**/
    public List<ModelClientInformation> getOnlineList(){
        return this.onlineList;
    }

    /**Function to update the specific Item**/
    public void updateTextView(int position, ModelClientInformation newItem){
        onlineList.set(position, newItem); //set the item 
        notifyItemChanged(position, newItem); //notify the adapter for changes
    }

    /*Get the position of item inside data list base on the given ID*/
    public int getPositionBaseOnItemID(String theID) {

        int length = onlineList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
            if(onlineList.get(i).getItemID().equals(theID)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1; //Item not found
    }
}
```

**Pojo**

```
public ModelClientInformation class{

    private String theID, text1, text2;

    public ModelClientInformation(String theID, String text1, String text2){
        this.theID = theID;
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public String getItemID(){
        return theID;
    }

    public String getText1(){
        return text1;
    }

    public String getText2(){
        return text2;
    }

}
```

I'm not so sure if this is how it should be done but I'm able to update the specific List Item and it's view base on position.

Thanks to everyone who gave me the idea of `notifyItemChanged()` ! hope this help the other too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onBindViewHolder (TheViewHolder holder, int position, List payload)

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HelloViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payload) {

        if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
             super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position , payloads);
        }else{

            for (Object payload : payloads) {
               if (payload instanceof String) {
                  holder.textView.setText(payload.toString) 
                 }
              }
          }

    }
```

And to update your textView you just need to call

`adapter.notifyItemChanged(position , "an string for example")`

This gives you a partial update of your view.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter,

```
String textToUpdate;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TheViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ModelClientInformation info = onlineList.get(position);

    holder.text1.setText(holder.getText1());// update the textview u want by setting the "textToUpdate" variable
    holder.text1.setText(holder.getText2());
}

public void updateTextView(String text){
    textToUpdate = text;
    notifyDatasetChanged(); 
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Create a a public static in the RecylerView class, simply assign a text in that method. Next, in the class where your geting a hook to the recycler view instance, make sure to add a onclick and ontouch interface to store the position of the selected text row. Use the recycler view instance to calling `notifyItemChanged`.

Here is a description from Documentation.

> notifyItemChanged added in version 22.1.0

void notifyItemChanged (int position)

Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed. Equivalent to calling notifyItemChanged(position, null);.

This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any reflection of the data at position is out of date and should be updated. The item at position retains the same identity.

Comment: what if I have `10 item` in my `DataList`? and I only want to `change one of the item` in the specific postion?

Comment: yes that works, just get a specific position with the onTouch or Onclick interface. Then invoke the method with that postion, make sure to notify your adaptor changes, as mentioned above.